# texpos's textblock and presentation:0

Tags: beamer, textpos

Currently, I place appendix buttons in beamer using this command:

```
\newcommand{\appendixbuttons}[1]{ 
    \begin{textblock}{16}(0,14.75)
        \raggedleft
        #1
    \end{textblock}
}
```

However, when I hide slides using `presentation:0`, the buttons appear on the following slides.
It seems like textblock does not respect `presentation:0`.
Anyway to hide textblocks in hidden frames?

(also, other non-TikZ solutions that place buttons at the bottom-right corner without changing the slide layouts, are also appreciated)

Edit: I added a minimal working example:
If I hide the first frame (using `<presentation:0>`) the button appears on the second frame.

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer} %,handout,aspectratio=169,

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % position text boxes


\newcommand{\appendixbuttons}[1]{ 
    \begin{textblock}{16}(0,14.75)
        \raggedleft
        #1
    \end{textblock}
}

\title{Beamer Template}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
        \maketitle
\end{frame}


%------------------------
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
%\begin{frame}<presentation:0>[noframenumbering]{Frame 1}

Blah Blah

\appendixbuttons{
    \hyperlink{mylink}{\beamerbutton{ref}}
}
\end{frame}
%------------------------


%------------------------
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}

Blah Blah

\end{frame}
%------------------------

%------------------------
\begin{frame}[label=mylink]{Frame 3}
Blah Blah
\end{frame}
%------------------------



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always include a small, but compilable test document, not just a code fragment.

Comment: If I go and spend the effort to actually create a test document from scratch and guess what packages etc are necessary to use your code fragment, then hiding buttons with `presentation:0` works just fine. We really need to see a MWE which allow us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: A MWE would be useful, but this sounds related to the problem that Sect.2.2 of the manual is discussing.  Try adding `\null`somewhere, so that there's not ‘nothing’ on the page.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. The OP has updated their question to add the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can warp the whole frame in `\mode<presentation:0>{...}` to hide the frame and the button:

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer} %,handout,aspectratio=169,

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % position text boxes

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

\newcommand{\appendixbuttons}[1]{ 
    \begin{textblock}{16}(0,14.75)
        \raggedleft
        #1
    \end{textblock}
}

\title{Beamer Template}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
        \maketitle
\end{frame}


\mode<presentation:0>{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Frame 1}

Blah Blah

\appendixbuttons{
    \hyperlink{mylink}{\beamerbutton{ref}}
}
\end{frame}
}
%------------------------


%------------------------
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}

Blah Blah

\end{frame}
%------------------------

%------------------------
\begin{frame}[label=mylink]{Frame 3}
Blah Blah
\end{frame}
%------------------------



\end{document}
```